# Information about network GUI in Raspbian

Tags: networking, raspbian-buster, desktop

A [GUI](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/desktop.md) is provided for setting up wireless connections in Raspbian with the Raspberry Pi Desktop. I'm having trouble finding information about it because I don't know what it is called.

Does it have a name? Is there any more technical documentation about it anywhere that I can read? Where can I see its source code?

I'm only interested in Raspbian Buster on the Raspberry Pi platform.

Comment: From your link, "Wireless connections can be made via the network icon at the right-hand end of the menu bar." That is how to get to the GUI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer my own question, this is an `lxpanel` plugin called `lxplug-network` and the source code is found here:

https://github.com/raspberrypi-ui/lxplug-network

It is based on 'Network Configurator' (a.k.a. `dhcpcd-ui`) by Roy Marples which is found here:

https://roy.marples.name/projects/dhcpcd-ui

Answer (score 1):

I think for a period Raspbian shipped with `wicd` to configure WiFi.

If anyone is looking for other connection managers:

- There's a command line version if `wicd` called `wicd-curses`.
- `nmcli` is the reference NetworkManager command line interface.
- `nm-applet` is the panel tool found on most heavier weight distributions like Ubuntu for interfacing with NetworkManager.

Comment: NetworkManager isn't supported by Raspbian.